# Word for an "everything you need kit"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Single word request. Looking for a less silly version of "kit and caboodle". A word for a kit that includes everything you need for a certain task.

I did look in a thesaurus, under "kit". None of the synonyms seemed to necessarily imply completeness or comprehensiveness of the kit.

Comment: _Vademecum_ is the classical term.

Comment: @JohnLawler *Vademecum* apparently means "a handbook or guide that is kept constantly at hand for consultation". I'm looking more for a word that is appropriate for a kit of tools.

Comment: @DepressedDaniel: That would be your ***toolkit*** if you want a single-word form.

Comment: Complete or self-contained would be my thinking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like *toolkit* but since it was already suggested (in comments), perhaps ... **apparatus**.

> [mass noun]     The technical equipment or machinery needed for a particular activity or purpose:
>   ‘*firemen wearing breathing apparatus’*.
>   — [O-D](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/apparatus)

Answer (score 0):

You may also say ***essentials*** (in the proper context; check the example below).

ODO:

> **[essential](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/essential)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> (usually **essentials**)
>   **1** A thing that is absolutely necessary:
>   ‘we only had the bare ***essentials*** in the way of equipment’